# VBA IF Then statements using string variables

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am working out a problem for my programming class and was wondering if I could get some help. The code below is supposed to get a discount for specific model numbers (AX1 and SD2) at 10% off. All other inputs are to be discounted at 5%. What happens now with the code is just a flat message box with the original entered price.

```
Private Sub DiscountCalc_Click()

Dim strModelNum As String
Dim curOrigPrice As Currency
Dim sngRate As Long
Dim curDiscount As Long
Dim curNewPrice As Currency


strModelNum = InputBox("Enter desired model number", "Price Lookup")
strModelNum = UCase(strModelNum)

curOrigPrice = InputBox("Enter the original Price", "Price Lookup")
sngRate = 0.1
curDiscount = 0.05


If strModelNum = "AX1" Then
  curNewPrice = curOrigPrice - (curOrigPrice * sngRate)
Else If strModelNum = "SD2" Then
  curNewPrice = curOrigPrice - (curOrigPrice * sngRate)
Else
    curNewPrice = curOrigPrice - (curOrigPrice * curDiscount)
End If

   MsgBox curNewPrice

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that you have an excess on one End If. Is this intentional or what? I have edited some lines for you.Thanks!

Comment: The extra endif was a result of being inexperienced. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
If strModelNum = "AX1" Or strModelNum = "SD2" Then
    curNewPrice = curOrigPrice - (curOrigPrice * sngRate)
Else
    curNewPrice = curOrigPrice - (curOrigPrice * curDiscount)
End If
```

Comment: Also need to change the two longs to doubles.  The long is rounding it to 0

Comment: Good catch - missed that

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

You will need to change Long to Double. Also you can compact your IF statements a little.

```
Private Sub DiscountCalc_Click()

Dim strModelNum As String
Dim curOrigPrice As Double
Dim sngRate As Double
Dim curDiscount As Double
Dim curNewPrice As Double


strModelNum = InputBox("Enter desired model number", "Price Lookup")
strModelNum = UCase(strModelNum)

curOrigPrice = InputBox("Enter the original Price", "Price Lookup")
sngRate = 0.1
curDiscount = 0.05


If strModelNum = "AX1" Or strModelNum = "SD2" Then
  curNewPrice = curOrigPrice - (curOrigPrice * sngRate)
Else
    curNewPrice = curOrigPrice - (curOrigPrice * curDiscount)
End If

   MsgBox curNewPrice

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look here:

```
Dim strModelNum As String
Dim curOrigPrice As Currency
Dim sngRate As Long
Dim curDiscount As Long
Dim curNewPrice As Currency
```

By using longs for the discount rates, I think you are asking for trouble.

```
Dim strModelNum As String
Dim curOrigPrice As Currency
Dim sngRate As Double
Dim curDiscount As Double
Dim curNewPrice As Currency
```

Comment: Changing from Long to Double was all that it needed. Thank you.